Why can setlogmask() on Linux only lower the priority - not raise it?
// Went to all users that are logged in: syslog(LOG_EMERG
syslog(LOG_ALERT, "1 %s: rcvd NV_update from Sub/Node: %d/%d\n", __func__, rcvd_subnet, rcvd_node);
syslog(LOG_CRIT, "2 %s: rcvd NV_update from Sub/Node: %d/%d\n", __func__, rcvd_subnet, rcvd_node);
syslog(LOG_ERR, "3 %s: rcvd NV_update from Sub/Node: %d/%d\n", __func__, rcvd_subnet, rcvd_node);
syslog(LOG_WARNING, "4 %s: rcvd NV_update from Sub/Node: %d/%d\n", __func__, rcvd_subnet, rcvd_node);
syslog(LOG_NOTICE, "5 %s: rcvd NV_update from Sub/Node: %d/%d\n", __func__, rcvd_subnet, rcvd_node);
syslog(LOG_INFO, "6 %s: rcvd NV_update from Sub/Node: %d/%d\n", __func__, rcvd_subnet, rcvd_node);
syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "7 %s: rcvd NV_update from Sub/Node: %d/%d\n", __func__, rcvd_subnet, rcvd_node);

setlogmask(LOG_UPTO(LOG_CRIT)) (got 1 and 2)

setlogmask(LOG_UPTO(LOG_NOTICE)) (got 1-5)

setlogmask(LOG_UPTO(LOG_DEBUG)) (got 1-6)

Without calling setlogmask(), I am getting LOG_EMERG...LOG_INFO.  Even calling setlogmask(0xff), I am not getting LOG_DEBUG.
"/etc/rsyslog.conf": *.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages

I tried calling setlogmask(0xff) and setlogmask(LOG_UPTO(LOG_DEBUG)).  I was expecting to see LOG_DEBUG in /var/log/messages.
I also tried:
setlogmask(LOG_MASK(LOG_EMERG)|LOG_MASK(LOG_ALERT)|LOG_MASK(LOG_CRIT)|LOG_MASK(LOG_ERR)|LOG_MASK(LOG_WARNING)|LOG_MASK(LOG_NOTICE)|LOG_MASK(LOG_INFO)|LOG_MASK(LOG_DEBUG))

I changed ".info" to ".debug" in "/etc/rsyslog.conf". Now, I'm getting LOG_DEBUG messages. That must set the maximum but I did not see that in the man pages.

The man page for syslog.conf that I looked at says "all messages of the specified priority and higher are logged". You didn't see that in the man pages?

https://linux.die.net/man/5/syslog.conf

I was looking at "man 3 syslog."  There is no man page for syslog.conf on this system. "man 3 syslog.conf" " man syslog.conf"

That's what google is for.

Searched for "setlogmask" "setlogmask no difference site:stackoverflow.com" "setlogmask no effect" "setlogmask "getting" "LOG_INFO" "not getting" LOG_DEBUG" "setlogmask "not working" -apple site:stackoverflow.com" "setlogmask "not working" -apple" "setlogmask "ignored" -apple" "setlogmask ignored -apple" "setlogmask ignored"

Your issue isn't with setlogmask, it's with syslog.conf.

Google "man setlogmask" will bring the man pages to the top of the results. And google "man syslog.conf" will get that man page.
